# Is it possible to initialize websocket connection without using the websocket built-in class?

Tags: angular, websocket, client-server

I've written a websocket server in nodejs that responds to handshake requests from the client side and everything is working well when I use the websocket class in angular as :

```
 const ws = new WebSocket(url);
```

Is it possible to create the websocket connetion without using the WebSocket class . I tried the following but it fails :

```
    const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Upgrade": "websocket",
    "Connection": "Upgrade",
    "Sec-WebSocket-Key": "dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==",
    "Sec-WebSocket-Version": "13"
  })
};
return this.httpClient.get<Observable<HttpClient>>('ws://localhost:3210', httpOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the npm package ngx-socket-io https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io 
It works very well